# Multiple Merge Replications on same SQL Server Database Conflicts

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have 2 separate merge replications on the same database on a server, one named 'POC' with a single subscriber running continuously, and another named 'Clubs' with ~50 subscribers. As of recently, the Club subscriptions have been coming up with errors saying 'The subscription to publication 'POC' has expired or does not exist'. It seems to be confusing the publications, but the sysmergesubscriptions and MSmerge_agents tables still point to the correct publications. Odd one - anyone seen something like this previously?

Comment: Push or pull subscriptions?  Also, do they share tables as well as the database?

Answer (score 2):

Check Subscription expiration interval & put the value the same for the 2 publications.